# XML Xquery: listing multiple subelements within main element instead of listing the same main element multiple times with different sub elements

Tags: xquery, flwor

I come from a SQL background but I have to work on a project for my company using Xquery, and I thought I would give it a shot.

I am working with an XML database for a client that stores information for who is the PM for a project and who is the analyst for a project. It has project elements that lists the projects with an id called pid, and has employee elements that lists which projects they PM (listed in a single comma separated string) and  which ones they manage (similarly listed). My task is to find all persons that both manage and pm a project, and to list said projects.

My question is: How do I return each project name under the same employee element, instead of returning 1 per element and listing the employee element multiple times?

```
for $e in //employee,
    $p in //project
where $e/contains(@analysts, $m/@pid)
and $e/contains(@pms, $m/@pid)
return
  <double-roles>
    <emp-name>{$p/name/text()}</emp-name>
    <proj-name>{$p/name/text(), “{“, $p/date/text(), “}”}</proj-name>
  </double-roles>
```

Comment: please post some test data to work with.

Comment: Are you sure you want a contains() comparison and not an "=" comparison (can't tell without seeing your data, but it looks fishy to me). Please also show desired output, for example I don't know what you mean by "under".

Comment: Where is `$m` bound in your code?